# CPU relaxation and delays in loops concerning GUIs

Tags: c, user-interface, cpu-usage, sdl-2

If you design a simple gui-application, you can [do something like this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/17_mouse_events/index.php):

```
while( running ){
    //Handle events on queue
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ){
        //User requests quit
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ){
            running = false;
        }                   
        //Handle button events
        for( int i = 0; i < TOTAL_BUTTONS; ++i ){
            gButtons[ i ].handleEvent( &e );
        }
    }
    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
    SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

    //Render buttons
    for( int i = 0; i < TOTAL_BUTTONS; ++i ){
        gButtons[ i ].render();
    }
    //Update screen
    SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
}
```

Now if you leave it like that, one of your cores should be at ~100% most of the execution-time, due to that endless loop. (Without any [delay-function](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay))

How can you relax a CPU while keeping the *GUI* of a single-threaded application responsive?

Comment: I'm afraid you're stuck with polling + small delay (like 10 ms). Check the CPU: it's probably 0%, and the app is stil very responsive. Try it.

Comment: Does SDL not provide some kind of `pause_until_next_event()` call?

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes there is [SDL_WaitEvent()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29), but what about running graphics/animations that are _independent_ from user-interactions? Unfortunately this is poorly documented here. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: @user1511417: Add a ~16 ms [timer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer) to wake up your `SDL_WaitEvent()` via a custom event.  That SDL wiki link has an example callback showing that.

Comment: `SDL_WaitEvent` blocks. So you cannot use it in mono-threaded...

Comment: @genpfault timer to call a blocking function? 1) that's cheating because the timer is probably threaded and 2) it probably doesn't work because WaitEvent blocks.

Comment: Oh dear. I had a look at the implementation of [SDL_WaitEvent()](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/0131b11bd03f/src/events/SDL_events.c#l672) and it seems that it simply waits via `SDL_Delay(10)` until there is an event.

Comment: :) SDL: "S" is for "simple" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe stating the obvious but as soon as you inject a small delay in a CPU intensive event polling loop, the CPU load plummets to almost 0%

```
while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ){
    //User requests quit
    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ){
        running = false;
    }                   
    //Handle button events
    for( int i = 0; i < TOTAL_BUTTONS; ++i ){
        gButtons[ i ].handleEvent( &e );
    }
    SDL_Delay(10);  // wait 10ms
}
```

you can adjust the delay but it will be barely noticeable (unless you use 500 as a value).

That allows to avoid threads & timers (which probably use threads, signals, well, not single threaded environment). Nice on very basic implementations of SDL on exotic platforms (ex: Nintendo DS)